# SwingUtilities.invokeLater in Web-application

Tags: java, swing

I was curious about the nature of swing in web-application. Currently I am engaged with an web-application which is using wicket. I did a small test. I have added a link and write the following code :

```
add(new Link<String>("link", new Model("link")) {

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
                frame.setContentPane(contentPane);                          
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        }
    }

});
```

And when I deploy the war into by server. When the link is clicked a UI is visible which closes on close button click. I want to know when the link will be clicked from client machine what behaviour this swing component will show? Would it be going to visible in client machine or in server.

Comment: @Tapas Think about it for a second: you just open a website, and click on a link, which goes to the server and somehow opens a `JFrame`? The `JFrame` isn't sandboxed as a Java Applet, so it has full permissions. This is not allowed, and _all_ of the above code runs on the server, making it impossible for it to appear on the client's machine no matter what.

Swing is for client-side development. This is not a client-side development. Either make a Java Applet, which the link embeds/uses, or deploy HTML (preferred!).

Comment: Just in the server. The client will receive just html code (possibly other content types) but the client wont see any swing code you execute on server side.

Comment: @pickypg thanks. Can I extend JApplet and use it to the web application?

Comment: @Tapas You could, but I cannot think of a site in recent memory that has included a Java Applet. And to be clear, you could not use it as the code attempts to above even if the above used an Applet. It would still all be happening on the server. You would have to deploy your Applet code so that it is accessible by the web request and reference that within the page (possibly generate the code with background JavaScript if you didn't want it on the page unless the link was clicked). I strongly suggest you use a different mechanism; preferably directly using HTML and Javascript.

Comment: @pickypg my project has a requirement to capture screen of client desktop. Without applet how can I able to do it using HTML? The above code was an experiment. The applet should be referenced properly.

Comment: @Tapas Ah, that's why you went this route. I'd might look at a standalone application that talks to a web service? I'm honestly not sure if an Applet has access to capture the user's screen. It might, but I just do not know.

Comment: @pickypg look at this site http://www.screenr.com/, they have an applet which records screen of client desktop. In my plan take multiple screenshots, convert those images to video.

Comment: @Tapas Ah. It looks like the Applet does have access to do it. You should look at the source of the "Record" part of the site. I think it might be informative as to how you launch/use a Java Applet (search for "applet archive" without quotes). If you look just above that, you'll see them using actually using JavaScript to talk to a separate applet defined [here](http://cdn.screenr.com/public/1.0/javascript/screenr.js). As with all sites, you should only use that as a resource for learning how things are done and not directly copy/paste their stuff.

Answer (score -1):

At the client machine of course. It will magically open a warp beam and materialize the servers cpu core at the client machine just before the invocation...

But wicket is nice, isnt it?

Comment: -1: Sarcasm won't help him learn that, just because you have a Swing-like library for web-programming, it is not actually Swing.

Comment: Sometimes it helps a lot pointing out the wrong view. World will not break for him for sure.